# Playing wav/mp3 from Windows 7 service

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-7, windows-services, naudio

I need to play a sound file (wav or mp3 is fine) from a service in Windows 7/2008... the way we did it in WinXP doesn't work anymore.  I've followed this question [Play wave file from a Windows Service (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143439/play-wave-file-from-a-windows-service-c/12431988#12431988)  with no success, in various combinations.  The sound plays fine through the debugger but once I install it as a service it doesn't play, and event logs prove the call is being made.  I've also followed the http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/c-service-play-sound-with-naudio.html link with the same result.

Code snippet follows below.  It is a C# service with VS 2010, .Net 4.0, NAudio 1.5.4.0.  I am using 
InstallUtil to install/remove the service.

WRT the code, I comment out the Wav or MP3 stuff and one of the methods each time... they all play the sound sucessfully.

```
    static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern Boolean AllocConsole();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            m_eventLog = new EventLog();
            m_eventLog.Source = "EventLoggerSource";

            if(args.Length > 0 && args[0].ToLower() == "/console")
            {
                AllocConsole();
                EventLoggerApp app = new EventLoggerApp();
                app.Start();

                m_eventLog.WriteEntry("INFO (Calling Player)");
                string fileFullPath=@"c:\aaasound\bunny_troubles.wav",fileFullPath2=@"c:\aaasound\dreams.mp3";

                // Wav file
                IWavePlayer wavePlayer=new WaveOutEvent();  // Method 1
                IWavePlayer wavePlayer=new WasapiOut(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.AudioClientShareMode.Shared,false,100); // Method 2   
                AudioFileReader audioFile=new AudioFileReader(fileFullPath);
                audioFile.Volume = (float)1.0;
                wavePlayer.Init(audioFile);

                // MP3 file
                IWavePlayer wavePlayer=new WasapiOut(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.AudioClientShareMode.Shared,true,100); // Method 1- EventSync/not both work
                IWavePlayer wavePlayer=new WasapiOut(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.AudioClientShareMode.Exclusive,false,100); // Method 2- EventSync must be false or throws an exception
                WaveStream mp3Reader = new Mp3FileReader(fileFullPath2);
                WaveChannel32 inputStream=new WaveChannel32(mp3Reader);
                WaveStream wavStream=new WaveChannel32(inputStream);
                wavePlayer.Init(wavStream);

                //this.wavePlayer.PlaybackStopped += new EventHandler(wavePlayer_PlaybackStopped);
                wavePlayer.Play();
                while(wavePlayer.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
```

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence of your question. Are you saying you can sometimes play audio in a service in Win 7 if you comment out some of your code?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that the code snippet as is won't compile... I comment out parts to try each of 4 methods (WaveOut/WasapiOut for both wav and mp3).  The audio doesn't play in any of those.

Comment: Pardon me for being slightly off-topic, but I'm curious: why would you write a service that plays any kind of sound?

Comment: there are plenty of reasons for a service to play a sound from a service.  if you're reading events from a hard ware input, such as a button and you want to beep when the button is pressed.  you need some kind of feedback to the user