# How to make a beeper program in form factor of ATL Service project?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, atl

How to make a program which beeps every 1 second in ATL.

I've tried to made a new ATL project (Service EXE) and in this method :

```
ProjectNameModule::ServiceMain(...){
    Beep(1000,50);
    //...
}
```

I've included this line

`Beep(1000,50);`

But running this, wouldn't give the expected result.

Any brilliant idea, please?

Comment: I could be wrong, but i think Beep-ing in a service is just impossible (i vaguely remember to have tried it myself).

Comment: try `Beep(1000, 60 * 1000);`

Comment: @deviantfan, because, the compiler haven't displayed any compilation error. Can you please advice me a good tutorial or book for building **Service EXE** ATL applications? Because, from where I'm learning this, it's very complex and hard to understand.

Comment: I found my thing again, it really does not beep just because it´s a service (in my case, no ATL is involved). It compiles fine too, the compiler won´t recognize such problems. Book etc.: As i have very little experience etc. with ATL, sorry, i can´t recommend you anything.

Comment: A service runs in session 0, isolated from the user session.  Where [nobody can hear it scream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286194/how-can-i-make-a-windows-service-beep).

Comment: @HansPassant, Can you please advice me a good tutorial or book for building Service EXE ATL applications? Because, from where I'm learning this, it's very complex and hard to understand.

Comment: @ABCmo: You're confusing two concepts. The basic rules for a service apply to all services regardless of the language/libraries/frameworks used to develop them. If you wrote a service in Visual COBOL, you still can't beep. ATL is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

ATL Service application, created from template, does not run as service until explicitly switched.

You need to run from command line: `MyProject.exe /service` and this will create the actual service. Then you start the service from management console etc., or it is started when external application requested COM object hosted by this service/application.

Service is unregistered with `/unregserver` or `/regserver`, in the latter case the application hosts COM classes from regular application, as opposed to service.

See also: [Media player as windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21857550/868014)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, running `MyProject.exe /Service` runs successfully, but, when I look into Windows Task Manager, MyProject.exe isn't in!

Comment: As I said, this **registers**, not starts the service. You can find your service running services.msc from Start Menu, Run.

Comment: I've built a service which runs correctly. Running the `MyProject.exe /service` doesn't create the service, did I misconfigured service?