# How to play audio file from visual basic with window service?

Tags: vb.net, audio, service, window

I tried to use `System.Media.SoundPlayer` and `My.Computer.Audio.Play()` but both of them cannot work in window service!
Any other method to process audio file from visual basic with window service?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143439/play-wave-file-from-a-windows-service-c

Comment: Problem solved, thank you very much!