# How to play sound on server by doing http request

Tags: php, powershell, iis

I have network monitoring server VM and always on win10 PC which displays monitoring dashboard. I want to implement sound alert on win10 PC when monitoring server generates alert.

Monitoring server runs CentOS7 and has functionality to execute bash script on alert event. I installed and configured IIS and php7.3 on win10 PC. My idea is to use

```sh
curl http://x.x.x.x/index.php
```

from server when alert is generated. index.php executes powershell script on win10 PC which plays alert sound.

`index.php`

```php
Shell_Exec ('powershell.exe C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sound.ps1');
echo Shell_Exec ('powershell.exe "Get-Process"); //This is for testing
```

`sound.ps1`

```bsh
$sound = new-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer;
$sound.SoundLocation="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\alert.wav";
$sound.Play();
```

When powershell script executed localy sound is played. When win10 PC accessed with curl I get information about running processes on computer, but no sound is played. As I understand powershell script is executed not as logged in user so windows doesn't play the sound. How can I make this work? Or is there better solution for this?

EDIT:
I added `start-transcript` line to `sound.ps1`:

```bsh
start-transcript -Path C:\ProgramData\log.txt
$sound = new-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer;
$sound.SoundLocation="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\alert.wav";
$sound.Play();
stop-transcript
```

Strangely I got like 0.5s playback of alert.wav when doing http request.

EDIT2:
Added Start-sleep -s 5 to the end of sound.ps1 and it works as intended. (alert.wav playback duration is 3s)

Answer (score 0):

In your `sound.ps1`, [you can use some C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44786179/584676) to `P\Invoke` (tap into C/C++ libraries) into the Win32 API to make a service able to play sound. Use `Add-Type` to compile the code:

```
Add-Type @"
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace Audio
{
    internal static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "PlaySound", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
        public static extern bool PlaySound(
            string szSound,
            System.IntPtr hMod,
            PlaySoundFlags flags);

        [System.Flags]
        public enum PlaySoundFlags : int
        {
            SND_SYNC = 0x0000,/* play synchronously (default) */
            SND_ASYNC = 0x0001, /* play asynchronously */
            SND_NODEFAULT = 0x0002, /* silence (!default) if sound not found */
            SND_MEMORY = 0x0004, /* pszSound points to a memory file */
            SND_LOOP = 0x0008, /* loop the sound until next sndPlaySound */
            SND_NOSTOP = 0x0010, /* don't stop any currently playing sound */
            SND_NOWAIT = 0x00002000, /* don't wait if the driver is busy */
            SND_ALIAS = 0x00010000,/* name is a registry alias */
            SND_ALIAS_ID = 0x00110000, /* alias is a pre d ID */
            SND_FILENAME = 0x00020000, /* name is file name */
            SND_RESOURCE = 0x00040004, /* name is resource name or atom */
            SND_PURGE = 0x0040,  /* purge non-static events for task */
            SND_APPLICATION = 0x0080, /* look for application specific association */
            SND_SENTRY = 0x00080000, /* Generate a SoundSentry event with this sound */
            SND_RING = 0x00100000, /* Treat this as a "ring" from a communications app - don't duck me */
            SND_SYSTEM = 0x00200000 /* Treat this as a system sound */
        }
    }
    public static class Play
    {
        public static void PlaySound(string path, string file = "")
        {            
            NativeMethods.PlaySound(path + file, new System.IntPtr(), NativeMethods.PlaySoundFlags.SND_ASYNC | NativeMethods.PlaySoundFlags.SND_SYSTEM);
        }
    }
}
"@
```

And then you can invoke it like so:

```
[Audio.Play]::PlaySound("C:\Folder\Containing\Audio\File", "sound.wav")
```

Note that I have only tested this with a `.wav` file but I would imagine it works for any format that Windows has an internal codec for. You can also play around with the `PlaySoundFlags` if you need to tweak the sound behavior at all.

Comment: Your approach works when script executed manually, but doesn't work from http request. I added `start-transcript` to `sound.ps1` and got these errors:
`Add-Type : (0) : Source file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\ek2k1awc.0.cs' could not be found`
`FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand`
`Add-Type : Cannot add type. Compilation errors occurred.`
Adnd some more compiler errors

Comment: Hmm.... that's interesting. I'm not sure why that step would fail. I don't have an HTTP server to test through, but what if you compile that code into a DLL, and load it from your `sound.ps1` like so: `Add-Type -Path C:\Path\To\Audio.dll`, where `Audio.dll` would be your built library?